# JQuery Conflict on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have installed a popup on a website but it won't fire at all, and I think it's a jQuery conflict. in the console it writes that it has fired but doesn't appear.

I have the [working version installed here](http://www.pestleandmortarcosmetics.com/pp.php) and works fine, but when I install it onto WordPress it won't fire.

Here is the code on the page to make it fire and this is accessed through PHP `file_get_contents()`

Here is the [link to the JavaScript file](http://www.pestleandmortarcosmetics.com/js/ouibounce.js)

Here is the [site link](http://www.pestleandmortarcosmetics.com/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // if you want to use the 'fire' or 'disable' functionn,
    // you need to save OuiBounce to an object
    var _ouibounce = ouibounce(document.getElementById('ouibounce-modal'), {
        aggressive: true,
        timer: 0,
        callback: function() { console.log('ouibounce fired!'); }
    });

    $('body').on('click', function() {
        $('#ouibounce-modal').hide();
    });

    $('#ouibounce-modal .modal-footer').on('click', function() {
        $('#ouibounce-modal').hide();
    });

    $('#ouibounce-modal .modal').on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: What is used to trigger the modal opening?

Comment: You have this error which prevents the JavaScript to move further: `Uncaught Error: no such method 'rotate' for tabs widget instance jquery.js?ver=1.11.0:2`

Comment: modal is triggered by leaving the page

Comment: The uncaught error isn't effecting this, on other pages that error does not appear but the modal won't fire

Comment: Add your script and js files into footer.php after wp_footer(). Try this, it may be solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

WRAP Up your scripts with
 ;(function($){ 
your scripts
})(jQuery);